# Disable force stop option for a service or an activity

Tags: service, kill

I have a requirement to create a service that cannot be stopped by end user. 
If the OS kills it, it is fine.

I have seen some processes that I am not able to quit. I need help on how this is possible.
For example, if i launch a 2.3 emulator and check the running services, one of the service - Japanese IME input does not a contain a stop option.

I cannot stop this service. Similarly with Swype. How is it possible to create such a service.

Thanks in advance.